# People can't use my v2+ semantic versioning release using gomodules

Tags: go, semantic-versioning, go-modules

I am maintaining a company *go* library which uses [Semantic Versioning](https://semver.org/) for releases. I switched to *go modules* for dependency management within the library and created a new release after *v2+*. I used the first strategy documented [here](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#releasing-modules-v2-or-higher) which involves modifying the *go.mod* file and import paths.

Now when people use the go get command (in a repo that is also using go modules) an error appears:

```
invalid version: module contains a go.mod file, so major version must be compatible: should be v0 or v1, not v3
```

Is anyone familiar with this issue?

---

To make things simpler I created a similar and simple example:

I have repo (*github.com/Graphmasters/testing-gomod-versioning*) with three files (not including *.gitignore*). These files are:

- *methods/method.go*

```golang
package methods

func Method() {
    println("Method")
}
```

- *main.go*

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/Graphmasters/testing-gomod-versioning/v3/methods"
)

func main() {
    methods.Method()
}
```

- *go.mod*

```
module github.com/Graphmasters/testing-gomod-versioning/v3

go 1.13
```

In the repo I created a release with the tag *v3.0.0* based on the branch with this code.

The aforementioned error is encountered when the following command is run in a repo that is using go modules:

```
go get "github.com/Graphmasters/testing-gomod-versioning@v3.0.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

The module name must be github.com/Graphmasters/testing-gomod-versioning/v3 or github.com/Graphmasters/testing-gomod-versioning.v3 and not github.com/Graphmasters/testing-gomod-versioning

Users should be able to do github.com/Graphmasters/testing-gomod-versioning/v3@v3.0.0 instead of github.com/Graphmasters/testing-gomod-versioning@v3.0.0

Example: You can check the mod file of the following v3 package - https://search.gocenter.io/gotest.tools~2Fv3/info?version=v3.0.0

Comment: In example I gave I already had **github.com/Graphmasters/testing-gomod-versioning/v3**.  Using `go get github.com/Graphmasters/testing-gomod-versioning/v3@v3.0.0`didn't work, although `go get github.com/Graphmasters/testing-gomod-versioning/v3` did but we need specific versions. I checked using downloading a specific version of **github.com/olivere/elastic** and that worked so it is unclear what is failing in this case.

Comment: Ok, thanks. In the example provided originally, the v3 suffix was missing from the `go get` example, so wasn't sure. Was v3.0.0 tag created with the go.mod referring to  github.com/Graphmasters/testing-gomod-versioning/v3 as the module name? What's the error?